# wxPython StaticText, TypeError: String or Unicode type required

Tags: python, string, list, text, wxpython

```
class popupInfo(wx.PopupWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        wx.PopupWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel = panel
        panel.SetBackgroundColour("GREY")

        st1 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[0],pos =(10,20))
        st2 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[1],pos =(10,40))
        st3 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[2],pos =(10,60))
        st4 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[3],pos =(10,80))
        st5 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[4],pos =(10,100))
        st6 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[5],pos =(10,120))
        st7 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[6],pos =(10,140))
        st8 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[7],pos =(10,160))

        self.SetSize((400, 400))
        panel.SetSize((400, 400))

        self.Centre()
```

I've got this class here, and I know everything is coming in correctly now. finalSemester1 is able to be accessed by all classes and/or functions.

The issue is the StaticText panel doesn't accept them as an argument for the string. It returns TypeError: String or Unicode type required... is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add str() before the argument that's printing error?

```
st1 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, str(finalSemester[0]),pos =(10,20))
```

If this isn't what you're looking for then I need more info.